# How to center the column headers in a Table?

Tags: tables

In a hurry..

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}|p{1in}|p{1in}|p{1in}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{S. No.} & {|c|Book Name} & Author &
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Publisher}\\
\hline
a & b & c & d\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}` for each column. (like you did in the first.)

Comment: If you still need to use the method of the p-column, consider using a minipage (aligned to the top, I'd advise) in the cells below (where you put the single dummy letters).

Comment: @subham soni: I added an answer to the above link, using the ` makecell` package, that can be handy here.